# Jasmine - How to set a timeout for a describe block?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a class which is poorly written, and get initialized only after a short timeout. (It's dependent in a 3rd party loading, so it's pointless to offer modifying the code. thank you)
Nevertheless, it needs to be unit tested.

What I have right now is the following structure:

```
describe('my tests', function() {

    var timeoutPromise = function () {
        /... return promise .../   
    } 

    it('test1', function (done) {
        timeoutPromise.then(function() {
            expect(...);
            done();
        });
    });

    it('test2', function (done) {
        timeoutPromise.then(function() {
            expect(...);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

That way I make sure all tests run after a few ms timeout. 
Is there is way to make the **whole describe block** run only after the timeout?
Something like

```
describe('my tests', function(done) {
      it(...);
      it(...);
      done();
}
```

Comment: You can create a `beforeEach(function(done) { ... })` block that makes `setTimeout(done, 1000);`. It will run before all `it()`s

Comment: But than you would be counting on each test to finish in less than 1000ms...

Comment: Nope, that timeout is blocking all tests until initialization is _done_ in `beforeEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `describe()` level `done` callback. From the [Jasmine 2.5 docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

> Calls to `beforeAll`, `afterAll`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, and `it` can take an optional single argument that should be called when the async work is complete.

However, you can do one time initialization in a `beforeEach()` on the same level as the `it()` blocks they belong to.

The following code will fullfill your requirements. It is inline commented:

```
describe('your tests', function() {

    var timeoutPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve, 4000);
    });

    // execute timeoutPromise and wait for it to resolve ...
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        timeoutPromise.then(function() {
            // timeout resolved, test initialization in this block done
            done();
        });
    });

    // for all following it()s the beforeEach() needs to complete 

    it('test1', function () {
        expect(...);
    });

    it('test2', function () {
        expect(...);
    });

    // ...

});
```